# CSS Infinite Loop issue

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-animations

I am happy with the current animation but Im having trouble getting the animation to start over from the beginning and looping infinitely. Can use some help on this one.I have also included the svg as well.I believe that the issue may be related to the forwards keyword as the animation runs sequentially from bar 1 to bar 7. Thanks again for the help as this has been a bit of a concern for a while now.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

svg g path {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 300ms forwards;
}

svg g path#bar1 {
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

svg g path#bar2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

svg g path#bar3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

svg g path#bar4 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

svg g path#bar5 {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

svg g path#bar6 {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

svg g path#bar7 {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="40pt" height="40pt" viewBox="0 0 236 202" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g>
            <g id="Group 2">
                <g id="Group 1">
                    <g id="surface1">
                        <g id="Group">
                            <path id="bar7" d="M236 32.6488L214.5 5L193 32.6488H204.579V192.693H223.897V32.6488H236Z"
                                fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_2">
                            <path id="bar6" d="M172 56V192.645H193.404V56H172Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_3">
                            <path id="bar5" d="M139 76V192.504H159.404V76H139Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_4">
                            <path id="bar4" d="M106 89V192.363H126.404V89H106Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_5">
                            <path id="bar3" d="M75 112V191.957H96.4042V112H75Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_6">
                            <path id="bar2" d="M43 130V192.957H64.4042V130H43Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <path id="bar1" d="M11 149V191.957H31V149H11Z" fill="white" />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Set the animations `iteration-count` to `infinte`

Answer (score 1):

> Check this out

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
     0% {
         opacity: 0;
    }

  50%{
    opacity:1
  }
     100% {
         opacity:0;
    }
}
 body {
     background: #444;
}
 path[class^="bar"] {
     opacity: 0;
     animation: fadeIn 5s ease;
   animation-iteration-count: 10;
}

 path.bar1 {
     animation-delay: 500ms;
}
 path.bar2 {
     animation-delay: 1s;
}
 path.bar3 {
     animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
 path.bar4 {
     animation-delay: 2s;
}
 path.bar5 {
     animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
 path.bar6 {
     animation-delay: 3s;
}
 path.bar7 {
     animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
<svg width="40pt" height="40pt" viewBox="0 0 236 202" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g>
            <g id="Group 2">
                <g id="Group 1">
                    <g id="surface1">
                        <g id="Group">
                            <path class="bar7" d="M236 32.6488L214.5 5L193 32.6488H204.579V192.693H223.897V32.6488H236Z"
                                fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_2">
                            <path class="bar6" d="M172 56V192.645H193.404V56H172Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_3">
                            <path class="bar5" d="M139 76V192.504H159.404V76H139Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_4">
                            <path class="bar4" d="M106 89V192.363H126.404V89H106Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_5">
                            <path class="bar3" d="M75 112V191.957H96.4042V112H75Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <g id="Group_6">
                            <path class="bar2" d="M43 130V192.957H64.4042V130H43Z" fill="white" />
                        </g>
                        <path class="bar1" d="M11 149V191.957H31V149H11Z" fill="white" />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks brother looks solid. Probably going to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

The animation-iteration-count CSS property sets the number of times an animation sequence should be played before stopping. Add the following to your `svg g path` CSS selector function `animnation-iteration-count: infinite`.

Comment: Seems simple enough but when adding the iteration count I  am getting the animation out of sink with the fade in now.

Comment: Should be `infinite` (also in your now redundant comment)... And what is `animnation`... Splellign maters!

Comment: @EdwardWilliamSams you may need to adjust your duration and fill-mode to get the right pairing for your delays

Comment: If you post a working snippit of your attempt I can likely get it figured out for you.

Comment: Ive added another css animation to manage opacity. ``` animation: fadeIn 1200ms ease-in-out 3s forwards, clear 4.5s forwards infinite``` but almost getting there. ```@keyframes clear {
 to{
   opacity: 0;
 }
  
}```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

svg g rect {
  opacity: 0;

  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 300ms infinite;

  &#bar1 {
    animation-delay: 500ms;
  }
  &#bar2 {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  &#bar3 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  &#bar4 {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  &#bar5 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  &#bar6 {
    animation-delay: 5s;
  }
  &#bar7 {
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg><g>
<rect fill="#bb22930" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</g></svg>
```

Comment: I believe the real issue here is that the forwards keyword allows the animation to be run sequentially from bar 1 to 7. This allows the animation to repeat but not in the correct time delayed order.

Comment: It,s better that If you put html and css and i run it

Comment: Just included the svg as well.